# jquery radio input checked from json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have three radio options for a list of questions:

```
<input type="radio" name="weight--'+index+'" value="not" />
<input type="radio" name="weight--'+index+'" value="somewhat" />
<input type="radio" name="weight--'+index+'" value="very" />
```

I have an object with the selected values:

```
{"weight--0":"not","weight--1":"somewhat","weight--2":"very"}
```

How can I set these options as selected using jquery?  I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.each()`([doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)) to iterate over your object, and then use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and `.val()` ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/val/)) to set the value of the radio button:

```
$.each(myObject, function(name, value) {
    $('input[name='+name+']').val([value]);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/9wsYK/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the desire element's checked attribute to 'checked'. Try giving the elements an id or class, (the name could work too), that they can be defined by, then use:

```
 $(/*selector*/).attr('checked', 'checked');
```